# A Coq proof of a theorem which turns a formula containing y into a formula containing f(x)

Tags: coq

I am trying to prove:

```
forall (T : Type) (U : Type) (P : T -> U -> Prop),
  (forall (x : T), exists (y : U), P x y)
    -> (exists (f : T -> U), forall (x : T), P x (f x))
```

In plain English, what I am trying to do is express the ability to turn `y` into `f(x)` in a formula. For example, changing `y = x + 1` to `f(x) = x + 1`.

A proof of the goal with the implication arrow reversed (turning `f(x)` into `y`) takes 4 lines. However, with this goal I can't think of anything to do after `intros`.

I'm not even sure this is possible in Coq. If not, is there a better way to express what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is a form of the axiom of choice and cannot be proved in Coq without extra axioms.  The problem is that in order to construct `f` you need to extract the element `y : U` from the proof of `exists y, P x y`.  This is forbidden in Coq by design, to ensure that proofs have no computational significance.

A way to get around this restriction is to replace the usual existential by its computationally relevant counterpart. We then get what Bob Harper calls the *theorem of choice*:

```
Goal forall (T : Type) (U : Type) (P : T -> U -> Prop),
  (forall (x : T), { y : U | P x y })
    -> (exists (f : T -> U), forall (x : T), P x (f x)).
Proof.
intros T U P H.
exists (fun x => proj1_sig (H x)).
intros x.
now apply proj2_sig.
Qed.
```